# How can I pass a string to Activity coming from Adapter to Fragment then to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

How can I pass data to activity from  Adapter to Fragment then to Activity

**This is my Adapter**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title01", title);
            bundle.putString("amount", Video1);
            bundle.putString("title", chat_ID);
            bundle.putString("desc", video_desc);
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action_global_frag_videoplay, bundle);
```

**This is my Fragment**

```
String str = getArguments().getString("amount");
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullscreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key1", str);;
                startActivity(intent);
```

**This is my activity**

```
  String value = intent.getStringExtra("key1");
```

[image]

**Keep getting this error when activity opens**
[image]

Comment: These code snippets show no error to fix. I advise using Android Navigation *Safe Arguments* to prevent any issues.

Comment: It looks like you're getting the NullPointerException because the intent in your FullScreenActivity is null. Could you show some code of your FullScreenActivity? Is it your main activity as well?

Comment: I've added it thank you